# Resolving EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

In my flutter application, time to time I am getting following error while storing image data into firebase storage and Firestore db(URL only).

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2667:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2575:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:87:59)
#3      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:50:14)
#4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
#5      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:380:22)
#6      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:83)
#7      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:106:19)
#8      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:333:9)
#9      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:26)
#10     SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:41:35)
#11     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:461:11)
#15     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:453:16)
#16     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:330:5)
#17     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1119:16)
#18     _ImageState.didUpdateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1091:7)
#19     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:57)

#44     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 6 frames from dart:async)

Image provider: NetworkImage("", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("", scale: 1.0)
```

Image data stores as follows.

```
  Map<String, dynamic> imageData = <String, dynamic>{
                            'refID': refId,
                            'type': 'POST',
                            'position': index,
                            'imgURL': _uploadImageList![index],
                            'create_timestamp':
                                TimestampModel.getCurrentTimestamp(
                                    'YYYYMMDDHHMINSS'),
                            'modified_timestamp': null
                          };
                          postDao.addSubDocument(refId, imageData);
 



 static String collectionName = 'posts';
  static String subCollectionName = 'images';

  void addSubDocument(String docId, Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    HeaderDetailDoc hederDetail =
        HeaderDetailDoc(firebaseDao.getCurrentUser()!.uid, 'users');
    hederDetail.addSubItem(
        docId: docId,
        collectionName: collectionName,
        subCollectionName: subCollectionName,
        data: data);
  }
```

Anybody has an idea, why this error throws rarely? Can it be a network issue?

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you log the URL that is causing the problem in your code, and then add the updated code and its output to your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your tip, after adding logs , I found that url get null value.